# Rename column elements from sampled vector sequentially in R

Tags: r

From a file with 230 rows of weights (unique weights = 9), the following weights are sampled in R:

5, 9, 7, 2, 8, 6, 2, 2, 2

Using a for loop, an empty matrix, and an input file that contains my full data set, these weights create the following data frame (full sampled data frame will be ~230 rows):

```
WeightSample <- structure(list(Type = c("Apple", "Banana", "Apple", "Apple", 
"Banana", "Orange", "Pear", "Banana", "Pear", "Pear", "Banana", 
"Pear", "Pear"), Color = c("Red", "Yellow", "Red", "Red", "Yellow", 
"Orange", "Green", "Yellow", "Green", "Green", "Yellow", "Green", 
"Green"), Weight = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Data frame I need:

```
WeightSampleNeed <- structure(list(Type = c("Apple", "Banana", "Apple", "Apple", 
"Banana", "Orange", "Pear", "Banana", "Pear", "Pear", "Banana", 
"Pear", "Pear"), Color = c("Red", "Orange", "Yellow", 
"Red", "Green", "Green", "Red", "Yellow", "Red", "Green", "Red", "Orange", "Yellow"), 
Weight = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 9L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

I have tried:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(WeightSample)[, num := rleid(WeightSample$Weight)]
```

Since this code assigns a consecutive number when the group changes, it is not picking up the 2, 2, 2 at the end of my sampled weight vector, which should instead be filled with consecutive numbers (i.e. 7, 8, and 9) for each row of data that is associated with the weight in the sampled vector. I am sampling weights from my full dataset 1000 times and therefore, the number of rows will change for each new data frame. I am therefore hesitant the code based on position will work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is it not changing for the top 5 5 5 or 9 9 and only should change for 2 at the end

Comment: Do you have any information regarding the unique values `5, 9, 7, 2, 8, 6, 2, 2, 2` as the 'WeightSample' doesn't show that info

Comment: I understand that part, but how are you differentiating the 2, 2, 2 at the end.  I would suggest to have a named vector for mapping because in the input it is not clear how to differentiate the 2 from another one

Comment: May be in your original sampling code, this should be a named vector i.e. `v1 <- setNames(c(5, 9, 7, 2, 8, 6, 2, 2, 2), seq_len(9))` and then you return the name of 'v1' instead of the value so that you get the expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe in the original code, we change the 'Weight' with the `names` of the 'Fruit.sample'

```
for (i in 1:1000) {
 
   Fruit.sample <- sample(AllFruit$Weight, size = 9, 
          replace = TRUE) #create a sample based on weight of fruit
   # // set the names of Fruit.sample as the sequence of those values
   names(Fruit.sample) <- seq_along(Fruit.sample)
   WeightSample <- NULL

for (k in seq_along(Fruit.sample)) {

    tmp <- AllFruit[which(AllFruit$Weight == Fruit.sample[k]),]
    # // replace the 'Weight' with the corresponding `names` of Fruit.sample
    tmp$Weight <- names(Fruit.sample[k])
    WeightSample <- rbind(WeightSample, tmp)
    }
}
```